# How to implement sum pooling using tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

sum pooling is not available in tensorflow. How do i add an sumpooling layer in my CNN model?

I've read the API documentation of tensorflow and sumpooling isn't available in it. Is there a way to implement SumPooling in my CNN model?